# Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat;

Tags: android, titanium

I am using titanium SDK 6.0.1.GA and compiling to Android.

I have this error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$zza;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza$zza;
[ERROR] 6 errors; aborting
```

Maybe it is related to geolocation.jar I guess though, couldn't find any solution.

I am using the ti.map and ti.ga for this application.

This is the [android.log](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1320870/build_android.log)

> These are the depiction of log below.

```
[INFO]  Running dexer: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools" "-jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/lib/dx.jar" "--dex" "--multi-dex" "--output=/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/build/android/bin/dexfiles" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/build/android/bin/classes" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/lib/titanium-verify.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.wikitude.ti/6.0.0/wikitudeand.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/com.wikitude.ti/6.0.0/lib/wikitudesdk_32bit.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.1.0/map.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.1.0/lib/google-play-services-base.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android/ti.map/3.1.0/lib/google-play-services-map.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/ti.ga/3.0.7/tiga.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/ti.ga/3.0.7/lib/google-play-services-analytics.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/nl.vanvianen.android.gcm/1.7/gcm.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/nl.vanvianen.android.gcm/1.7/lib/gcm-server.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/nl.vanvianen.android.gcm/1.7/lib/google-play-services-gms.jar" "/Users/whitebear/CodingWorks/httproot/okayamaARNew/modules/android/nl.vanvianen.android.gcm/1.7/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/kroll-v8.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-analytics.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/aps-analytics.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-android.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/kroll-common.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/titanium.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-multidex.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-filesystem.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-app.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-ui.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-media.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-appcompat.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-v4.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-cardview.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/cardview-v7-23.0.1.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-locale.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-network.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-xml.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-platform.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-gesture.jar" "/Users/whitebear/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.0.1.GA/android/modules/titanium-geolocation.jar"
[ERROR] Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR]   
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$1;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/MessengerCompat$zza;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza;
[ERROR] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lcom/google/android/gms/iid/zzb$zza$zza;
[ERROR] 6 errors; aborting
```

Comment: Post your gradle files.  This means 2 different libraries are including the same library in different versions.

Comment: I don't use gradle though, I attached android.log file. The libraries might be included are these three....  ti.ga , ti.map nl.vanvianen.android.gcm  https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map https://github.com/benbahrenburg/Ti.GA https://github.com/morinel/gcmpush

Comment: Then post whatever build system files you are using that lists your dependencies.  My suspicion would be nl.vanvianen.android.gcm, as its obviously providing part of gcm but is not an official gcm package, so probably isn't up to date with other packages (and in fact hasn't had any checkins since August).

Comment: Actually after looking again-  the odds that nl.vanvianen.android.gcm and github.com/morinel/gcmpush conflict are high-  they both work with gcm, but its inlikely they both work on the same version.

Comment: You are right , if I omit including the  nl.vanvianen.android.gcm. it works. I will search something to do gcmpush instead of this library.

Answer (score 1):

Get the google-play-services-base.jar from ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/android and replace it in all your modules, so you can be sure that there won't be a conflict between them.
Now you have to get rid of the classes inside the others jar (like google-play-services-analytics.jar for instance) which are already inside the google-play-services-base.jar, so unzip the guilty library, remove the duplicated classes, and re-create the jar with the command:

```
jar cf google-play-services-analytics.jar ./com
```

For doing these things you can also use proguard, but the procedure above could be enough. I wrote about this problem on my blog http://mpic.it/snellire-la-libreria-google-play-services-jar-con-proguard/ but it's in Italian.